# Purchases.getProducts returns empty array with revenueCat

Tags: android, react-native, revenuecat, android-inapp-purchase

I had also asked this question on the RevenueCat forum, but I felt the need to ask it here as well. https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/purchases-getproducts-returns-empty-array-3899

I can make purchases on the iOS side without any issues, but as indicated in the logs on Android, the list is coming up empty.

[image]

Configure

```
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {

   try {

   Purchases.configure({

   apiKey: REVENUE_CAT_IOS_API_KEY,

   appUserID: user?.uid,

   })

   } catch (error) {

   console.error('error configuring revenuecat for iOS', error)

   await analytics().logEvent('error_configuring_revenuecat_for_ios')

   }

   } else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {

   try {

    Purchases.configure({

    apiKey: REVENUE_CAT_ANDROID_API_KEY,

    appUserID: user?.uid,

  })

 } catch (error) {

  console.error('error configuring revenuecat for Android', error)

  await analytics().logEvent('error_configuring_revenuecat_for_android')

 }

}

 

This is where I am trying to fetch the products.

  const purchaseStoryToken = async () => {
    try {
      useSetLoading(true)

      const products = await Purchases.getProducts(['dk_story_token'])
      console.log('fetched products', products)
      const storyTokenProduct = products?.[0]
      console.log('storyTokenProduct', storyTokenProduct)

      await Purchases.purchaseStoreProduct(storyTokenProduct)
    } catch (e) {
      analytics().logEvent('error_purchasing_product')
      console.log('error in purchaseStoryToken', e)
      throw e
    } finally {
      useSetLoading(false)
    }
  }
 LOG  fetched products []
 LOG  storyTokenProduct undefined
 LOG  error in purchaseStoryToken [TypeError: Cannot read property 'identifier' of undefined]
```

[image: Revenue Cat Products]

[image: Revenue-cat Offerings]

[image: Revenue-cat Entitlements]

[image: Google play console In-App products I have]

[image: Subscriptions]

[image]

[image]

I created APK and tested it on a real device as well as on the simulator. The result is the same.

I might have overlooked something, please allow me to know if more information is needed.

Questions:
1- Where should the 'dk_story_token' inside the 'Purchases.getProducts(['dk_story_token'])' code exactly come from? Where can I retrieve this information, within the Google Play Console or in Revenue Car's dashboard? Where did this string come from?

As seen in the first screenshot I provided, the 'dk_story_token' is present in the Apple Developer Console for in-app purchases, which is why I can make purchases on iOS. However, I cannot do the same on Android.

Shouldn't it be present and functional in the 'In-app Products' section that I created on Android? Why is this array coming up empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using "getOfferings" and "getCustomerInfo" instead of "getProducts" and it is working.

```
import Purchases from "react-native-purchases";

// ... getPlatformKey
const apiKey = getPlatformKey();
Purchases.configure({ apiKey });

async function getPackages() {
  try {
    const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
    const packages = offerings?.current?.availablePackages || [];

    // ... rest and catch     
  }
}

async function getActivePlans() {
  try {
    const results = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();
    const customerInfo = results?.customerInfo || results;
    const activePlans = customerInfo.entitlements.active || {};

    // ... rest and catch 
  }
}

async function purchasePkg(pkg) {
  // pkg of packages form getPackages
  try {
    const results = await Purchases.purchasePackage(pkg);

    // ... rest and catch 
  }
}
```

Comment: "await Purchases.getOfferings();" throw "[Error: There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details.]"

Comment: This what they suggested in their docs
[link](https://github.com/RevenueCat/react-native-purchases/blob/main/examples/MagicWeather/src/screens/PaywallScreen/index.js#L24-L33) 

These two Links where useful for me

[link](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-products) 

[link](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/getting-started)